# Is there a closed form for $\cos(\frac{\pi}5)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was wondering if there was a closed form for $\cos(\frac{\pi}5)$?

We have the following in closed form:

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}2)=0$$

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}3)=\frac12$$

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}4)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$$

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}6)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$$

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}8)=\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}2$$

But perhaps a solution to $\cos(\frac{\pi}5)$?

Comment: https://math.la.asu.edu/~surgent/mat170/Exact_Trig_Values.pdf

Comment: One way to study this: find sides and angles in the regular pentagon inscribed in the unit circle.

Comment: $\frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{4}$

Comment: In relation to the comment of @GEdgar, Euclid proved that the regular pentagon is constructible. In modern language that construction can be used to derive an expression for $\cos(\pi/5)$ using only arithmetic and square roots.

Comment: See http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos36.shtml and http://www.math-only-math.com/exact-value-of-cos-36-degree.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a isocles triangle $ABC$, with $AB=AC$, $\angle A=\frac{\pi}{5}$.

Draw the angle bisector of $\angle B$, which meets $AC$ on point $P$. Note that $BC=BP=AP$.

Using this, one can calcualte that $AC=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \times BC$.

Using this, $\cos \frac{\pi}{5}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$

Comment: :D  How about we say $\cos\frac\pi5=\frac\phi2$?  Using the golden ratio is always the best way to go.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I guess you could say that. The golden ratio arises from the regular pentagon.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{5}) = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}.$